# How to add router-link in vue js dynamically

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I am facing a very interesting problem. I am returning some html from server as json. My return html string look like this

`str2: " <span class="card_top_com_span link_color"  ><router-link to="/profile/sadek3/about">numan sir</router-link> </span></span>, <span class="card_top_com_span link_color" ><router-link to="/profile/sadek3/about">sadek mia</router-link> </span> and 4 of your firiends commented on this post"`

This is returned from server. Now I want to add some spa link.

It can be `nuxt link, @click event for routing or a </router-link>`

I am using v-html in my front end to out put html. It does output correctly.

Is there anyways of doing this?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand why you don't just get your server to return that data in a structured JSON like {"link":"/profile/..." and re-construct HTML markup within Vue (which is generally the point of SPAs)

Comment: Yap this is one solution I can do with some for loop in vue.

Comment: If you generate the HTML from your server, then whatever solution you come up with would be a hack to parse the string and extract the data you want. You're then fighting the framework, impacting performance + making things harder for yourself. Just send structured JSON =)

Answer (score 2):

As said in the comments, it's way better to respond from your server with structured JSON data. However, you can make it work, but you need to use a `<component></component>`. Just using `v-html` won't work if you have `router-link`:

```
<div id="app">
  <component :is="{template: theString}"></component>
</div>

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
  data: {
    theString: '<h3>Something Cool</h3>'
  }
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/to8smxfb/

PS: You also need to make sure that `theString` only contains one root element. You can wrap your string into `<div></div>` for example.